# How do I add a blockquote right after a directive?

Tags: restructuredtext

I am trying to insert a blockquote right after the [more](http://tinkerer.me/doc/tinkering.html#posts) directive, which doesn't take any arguments:

```
First paragraph.

.. more::

    Blockquote here!

    -- Author

Second paragraph.
```

When I build this document, my blockquote is lost. How can I seperate these two without adding a paragraph in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a comment after the directive, like this:

```
First paragraph.

.. more::

..

    Block Quote

    --Author

Second paragraph.
```

[This section](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#block-quotes) explains that empty comments are the preferred method of escaping any constructs that would otherwise interfere with a block quote.